# Drupal 7 easy breadcrumb module hides breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs

When I install the easy breadcrumbs module my breadcrumb disappears. 
I am wondering if there is a particular settings that I need to change. If I am on the homepage the breadcrumb home is displayed. As soon as I install the easy breadcrumb the breadcrumb is hidden. I tried clearing the cache but that didn't fix the problem. I also changed the theme to see if it was a theme issue but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) project page. The answer to your question is in the Configuration section of it. Here is a quote from module's project page:

> To start using it, just go to the admin modules page (URL admin/modules/list), locate and activate it under the category "others", then go to the blocks list page (URL admin/structure/block) and locate the block named "Easy Breadcrumb", and configure it like any other block (region, URLs, etc.).
>
> The configuration page of this module is under Admin > Configuration > User Interface > Easy Breadcrumb (URL admin/config/user-interface/easy-breadcrumb).
>
> Configurable parameters:
>
> - Disable the default Drupal's breadcrumb.
> - Include / Exclude invalid path alias as plain-text segments.
> - Exclude some paths from the segments to be generated.
> - Include / Exclude the front page as a segment in the breadcrumb.
> - Customize the title of the front page segment in the breadcrumb.
> - Include / Exclude the current page's title as a segment in the breadcrumb.
> - Use the real page's title when it is available instead of always deducing it from the URL.
> - Print the page's title as a link or as plain-text segment.
> - Use a custom separator between the breadcrumb's segments.
> - Choose a transformation mode for the segments' title.
> - Make the 'capitalizator' ignore some words (words not to be capitalized).